# anonymous authentication with AWS cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

Is it possible to use anonymous authentication with AWS cognito? I would like to know if it is possible to do anonymous authentication and control S3 access rights through it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. AWS Congnito Identity Pool support [Unauthenticated Identities](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/identity-pools.html#authenticated-and-unauthenticated-identities):

> Amazon Cognito identity pools support both authenticated and **unauthenticated** identities. Authenticated identities belong to users who are authenticated by any supported identity provider. **Unauthenticated identities typically belong to guest users**.

How to set them up is explain in [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/identity-pools.html#enable-or-disable-unauthenticated-identities).

Comment: Is is possible to do anonymous authentication and control S3 access rights through it?

Comment: @Marcin Is it also possible to associate custom information with unauthenticated identity? For instance, in MS Playfab you can use deviceID as token for anonymous login, storing data associated to a user without requiring them to ever enter username or password.

Comment: @HidetakaKo, yes, you would associate the IAM Role of your choosing for the identity pool with guest access.